# how to debug apache's allow/deny rules?

Tags: apache, security, configuration

I tried adding `LogLevel Debug` but all i get is

```
client denied by server configuration: /somedir/html/file.html
```

I have a complex allow/deny rule for one location, that can be reduced to this to reproduce my issue:

```
<LocationMatch "/somedir/(.*)\.html" >

 SetEnvIf Referer "^https?\:\/\/[^\/\?\#]*domain\.com(\:\[0-9]+)?([\/\?\#]|$)" SAME_ORIGIN_HOST_CHECK=1
 SetEnv DEV_BUILD_ALLOW 1

 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from env=SAME_ORIGIN_HOST_CHECK
 Allow from env=DEV_BUILD_ALLOW
</LocationMatch>
```

the referrer coming from domain.com is working fine, but setting the dev build var is ignored.

Is there any way to get more granular log output, like is possible with mod rewrite, but for the allow/deny rules?

Comment: I currently have a similar problem with `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow`... it just doesn't do what I believe it should do, and apparently there's no debugging for this at all :/

Comment: This is old :) i ended up finding the problem for this TODAY, by some weird coincidence. my bug was as stray backslash on `\[0-9]`... should have been `[0-9]`. what are the odds you comment on that month old question the day before i have to debug it again? anyway, sorry to be of no help. in this case it was just a bad regexp. and i did NOT find any better way to debug it other than removing individual lines, restarting apache, repeat... :(

Comment: I've found the problem in the meantime. Turns out that while the order of `Allow`/`Deny` statements may not matter (at least the docs say so), the order of `<Directory>` blocks do matter very much. I had to move my `<Directory>` block around to resolve my issue.